# Disabled and checked on radio button is not working

Tags: html, css, angular

In an Angular HTML file, there are radio buttons with common names and I am trying to update their disabled and checked property from a .ts file which is not taking place. Below is my code

```
let elements = document.getElementsByName('option');
 console.log(elements.length);
    for(var i=0;i< elements.length;i++){
        elements[i].setAttribute('disabled','true');
        elements[i].setAttribute('checked','false');
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You probably mean a select (not radio). Try using `getElementsByTagName` instead

Comment: option is common name for all radio inputs

Comment: radio uses input, not select <input type="radio">

Comment: yes i have written <input type="radio" name="option" > please help on this i am on this for hours

Comment: You could probably achieve what you want with data binding. Please show us your HTML template.

Comment: <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option3"  (change)="onchange($event)">
    {{selectedQuestion?.Option3}}
    </label>

Comment: questions comes one by one from database on 25 second timer

Answer (score 0):

Try influencing attributes in this order:

1. Try getting or setting a specific property, like `elements[i].disabled = true`
2. If there is no specific property, use `getAttribute()` or `setAttribute()`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you manipulating DOM directly? With ng you are supposed to use data/attribute bindings

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="model.isChecked" ng-disabled="model.isDisabled" />
```

Comment: Side note: you posted AngularJS, not Angular code :)

Comment: is there any such directive for angular4 it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code:

**component**

```
let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(elements);
    for(var i=0;i< elements.length;i++){
      elements[i].checked = true;
      elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwkwnf)

Comment: i implemented your solution it is working but there is one issue when next question comes radio button  that was previously selected remains checked

Comment: can u please help me on that

Comment: Ofc, Why not you reset the inputs?

Comment: my .html code <label class="btn btn-secondary">

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="Option4" (change)="onchange($event)">
    {{selectedQuestion?.Option4}}
    </label> questions come one by one from database after 25 seconds

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: thanks a lot sir my net was not working thats why i replied late but your solution saved my day

Comment: If it was a best solution for you please check it  and Vote up

Comment: my reputation is below 15 so i cant vote on anything i am new to stackoverflow